# Get ULS log records programatically

Tags: 2010, development, powershell, logging, uls

Is it possible to retrieve records from ULS log using C#/SharePoint API without having to manually parse log files? I would like to display logged messages on a custom web page, and I would like to filter these messages beforehand (based on area, category etc.). Ideally, it should be as simple as binding log records to a grid where `Area=someValue`.

There is plenty written about how to *write* to ULS log (using `SPDiagnosticsServiceBase`), but I can't find anything on how to read it. In SP2013, there is [SPULSRetriever](http://www.sharepointdoug.com/2013/06/get-log-entries-from-sharepoint-2013.html), but nothing similar seems to exist in SP2010.

**UPDATE**
As suggested by the answer, here's one way to do it by invoking powershell.

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{                
    ps.AddScript("Add-PSSnapin \"Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell\"");

    // example: call "Get-SPLogEvent -StartTime (Get-Date).AddHours(-24) | Where-Object {$_.Area -eq 'SharePoint Foundation'}" to get log records of last 24 hours
    string script = String.Format("Get-SPLogEvent -StartTime (Get-Date).AddHours(-24)");
    ps.AddScript(script);
    ps.AddCommand("where-object");
    ps.AddParameter("filterscript", ScriptBlock.Create("$_.Area -eq 'SharePoint Foundation'"));                             
    Collection<PSObject> output = ps.Invoke();

    foreach (PSObject outputItem in output)
    {
        if (outputItem != null)
        {                    
            // Display logged messages.
            Console.WriteLine(outputItem.Members["Message"].Value);                     
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One quick way would be to have the C# program call PowerShell cmdlets to read the ULS log files and then use the results to display on a custom web page. The SharePoint PowerShell cmdlets (e.g., Get-SPLogEvent & Get-SPLogLevel) would provide the 'filtering' as needed -

[Executing PowerShell scripts from C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c.aspx)

[How to run PowerShell scripts from C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C)

[Using Windows Powershell Cmdlets with ULS Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff595318%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[Logging and events cmdlets (SharePoint 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee890114%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[Using Get-SPLogEvent to retrieve logs based on correlation id](http://www.mysharepointadventures.com/2011/08/175/)

[Get-SPLogEvent (PowerShell cmdlet)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607589%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

[Get-SPLogLevel (PowerShell cmdlet)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607576%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Also to improve Get-SPLogEvent performance, [this](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2012/04/26/my-simple-powershell-script-for-finding-those-troublesome-correlation-ids.aspx) is useful

Comment: Another thing I remembered that is worth pointing out is that Get-SPLogEvent only searches the local server, which may not be desirable if multi-server environment is used.

Comment: I haven't tried it (yet) but PowerShell remoting in PowerShell 2.0 has been enhanced further in PowerShell 3.0 with a lot of new remoting features. It may help in accessing log files in other servers in the farm.

Comment: Then there's the ConvertTo-Html cmdlet to make the html pages for results display - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156817.aspx